# The cardinality of power set $2^A$ is strictly bigger then cardinality of a set $A$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Actually the proof is obvious for finite sets. Because we can easily proof with induction. But it doesn't seem so for infinite ones. I know that there is a proof using diagonal argument and constructing the set $S_f=\{a\in A : a\notin f(a)\}$. So after some steps we get contradiction that there exists surjective function from $A$ to $2^A$. But how do we know that we can construct such set as $S_f$? For example consider $M=\{x : x\notin M\}$.
This was first question. The second one is - "Is there another proof for infinite case when A is infinite?".

Comment: by definition is kwon that if $A$ is a set then, there is a set such that $\{x\in A|P(x)\}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we are given a set $A$ and a specification $\varphi(x)$, the [axiom schema of comprehension (or specification)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_schema_of_specification) allows us to construct the set $\{x\in A:\varphi(x)\}$. Here $\varphi(x)$ is ‘$x\notin f(x)$’. I am not aware of any fundamentally different proof for arbitrary sets.

Comment: Well, there is a fundamentally different proof that there is no surjection from $A$ onto the set of well-orderable subsets of $A$.